# How can I input vectors of numpy arrays into an equation?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vector

Say I have a numpy array of 5 vectors and the dimensionality didn't matter, and I wanted to input those into an equation, but only between each pair of vectors e.g.
1 and 2,
1 and 3,
1 and 4,
1 and 5,
2 and 3,
so on and so forth. How can I do this in python? For example if I wanted to find the difference between the each of the two vectors? How can I do this without doing each one by hand? Is your answer scaleable to 100 vectors?

Comment: `itertools.combinations`?

Answer (score 0):

use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), i.e put vectors in different dimensions:

```
ten_vectors=np.random.rand(10,2)

ten_vectors_x=ten_vectors.reshape(10,1,2)
ten_vectors_y=ten_vectors.reshape(1,10,2)

def f(vx,vy): return vx-vy # for example.

res=f(ten_vectors_x,ten_vectors_y)
#res.shape is (10,10,2)
```

Then `res[i,j]` is `v[i]-v[j]`.